how can i send username and password of api 'basics' with get request in dio package in flutter
how can i send username and password of api 'basics' with get request in dio package in flutter i try it several times not working ,only with HTTP package*
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:test/paymentmodel.dart';

class ApiService {
  final Dio dio;
  ApiService(this.dio);
 
  Future<List<PaymentMethodModel>> getall() async {
     String username = '11191082';
  String password = 'dayfreetrial';
  String basicAuth =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
  print(basicAuth);
    var response = await dio.get(
        'http://example-001-site1.atempurl.com/api/SalesInvoice/GetAllPayments',
        options: Options(headers: <String, String> {
          'Authorization':
              basicAuth,
        }));
    

    List<dynamic> datat = jsonDecode(response.data);
    List<PaymentMethodModel> storesList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < datat.length; i++) {
      storesList.add(
        PaymentMethodModel.fromJson(datat[i]),
      );
    }

    return storesList;
  }
}

}
}
